# A customized enumerated list

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

page 23 blah blah blah blah

page 61 and so on

page 82 whatever

I would like something like an enumerated list in which the numbers are page numbers formatted as above. The paragraph that follows "page 23" would be horizontally to the right of the words "page 23".

How can that be done?

Comment: How are the page numbers determined?

Comment: @Bernard : By the user.

Comment: You mean it's no gradually incremented counter? Are they cross-references?

Comment: @Bernard : They are not cross-references. They do not refer to pages in the same document.

Comment: Look at the `description` environment of the `enumitem` package: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items in `enumerate` can be given arbitrary labels by placing the label text as the optional argument

```
 \item[my label]
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[page 23] blah blah blah blah
\item[page 61] and so on
\item[page 82] whatever
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```